# How to change the Firefox Sync Server?

Tags: firefox

I just noticed that Firefox has different sync server for different regions. My bookmarks are all synced to one server. However, my newly installed firefox on another machine cannot sync them due to region difference.

I checked the `about:config` page and changed all the config entries which contain the word `sync`. Such as below ones (and others I didn't list them all):

```
services.sync.serverURL
services.sync.statusURL
```

But the account still failed to sign in.

I heard that the `prefs.js` file in the Firefox profile folder (`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xxxxxxxx.default`) stores all the settings, so I copied the whole `xxxxxxxx.default` folder from my other firefox instance. But still don't work. The sync URL still doesn't change and I still cannot get my bookmarks.

So what decides the sync server for a Firefox instance?
Anyone knows how to change it?

Comment: See if [this article](http://blog.hansenpartnership.com/getting-your-old-sync-server-to-work-with-new-firefox/) helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly same problem (on linux).As for me, the very ugly way worked. I downloaded firefox version 20, I run it a setup sync old way. This seemed to be ok, but synchronization showed some mistakes. Then I run new firefox, where sync seemed to be not setup, but when I run "Sync setup...", old dialog for setup appeared.

Answer (score 0):

An option could be to use your [own sync server](https://github.com/mozilla-services/syncserver).

Anyway, according to the readme there, you perhaps don't alter the right firefox config setting.

> Now go into Firefox's about:config page, search for a setting named "tokenServerURI", and change it to point to your server:
>
> `identity.sync.tokenserver.uri:  http://localhost:5000/token/1.0/sync/1.5`
>
> (Prior to Firefox 42, the TokenServer preference name for Firefox Desktop was "services.sync.tokenServerURI". While the old preference name will work in Firefox 42 and later, the new preference is recommended as the old preference name will be reset when the user signs out from Sync causing potential confusion.)

Comment: Actually I changed all the config entries related to `sync` or containing a URL, such as `services.sync.syncKeyHelpURL`, `services.sync.statusURL`. But seems not working.